# Get process image path of renamed executable

Tags: windows, powershell, process, taskmanager

I'm trying to get the "true" image path of a process that as been renamed while running in order to identify the users that are still running the old executable file.

For exemple, let's say I have the executable file "C:\myexe.exe" running on multiple users sessions.
[image]
My team need to put a new version **during production** without interrupting our users. The only solution is to rename the current executable like "C:\myexe_old.exe" and put a **new** "C:\myexe.exe".

So now, we have **two** files.
When I open Task Manager, I can identify which users are running the old .exe file by displaying the "Image path name" column.
[image]

I'm trying to get the same information in PowerShell but the path I get is always "C:\myexe.exe".

I have tried using `Get-Process` and `Get-CimInstance Win32-Process` and look at all the properties but nothing indicate the "true" path ("C:\myexe_old.exe").

[image]

If Task Manager can retrieve this information, surely we can but I have no idea how.

Comment: You do refresh the info you get in Powershell don't you? And did you stop the running exe and restart it after renaming?

Comment: @Theo I think you didn't quite understood my issue. I actually want to retrieve the running process that still use the old exe. In order to identify which users are not running the new version. And I can't kill the processes because I don't want to disturb the users.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that from reading your question. It might be best if you [edit] and make that clearer in the question itself

Comment: @Theo I edited it. Thank you. Do you have an idea for the actual issue by chance?